# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>' to 'int'

Tags: c#, sql

How to convert IEnumerable of dynamic type to int or string? This is my code and I can't figure out how to get int from sql query

```
public class SaveCustomerData : IDisposable
{
private readonly string _connectionString;
private readonly Database _db;

public SaveCustomerData(string connectionString)
{
    _connectionString = connectionString;
    _db = Database.Open(connectionString);
}

public void Insert(string fname, string lname, string phone, string cellno, DateTime dob, string gender, string address, string address2, string creditno, string city, string postalcode, string email) {

    **int uid = _db.Query("SELECT UserID FROM UserProfile WHERE Email=@0",email);**



    _db.Execute("INSERT INTO Customer_Table (customer_fname, customer_lname, customer_phone, customer_mobile, customer_dob, customer_gender, customer_address, customer_address2, customer_creditno, cutomer_city, cutomer_postal, customer_email) VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12",
        fname, lname, phone, cellno, dob, gender, address, address2, creditno, city, postalcode, uid);
}
```

Comment: Just a note: your `INSERT INTO` statement has a syntax error (missing parenthesis). You'll get an exception for that as soon as you fix the exception you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

use [`db.QueryValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.queryvalue%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) instead of Query

```
  int key = (int)_db.QueryValue("SELECT UserID FROM UserProfile WHERE Email=@0",email);
```

Comment: The second query is throwing following exception:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@12".

Comment: Your second query is wrong,google and check you will get n number of results